# Can we integrate VM instances with Testcafe server and run tests on those instances?

Tags: safari, automated-tests, virtual-machine, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have some test cases which will need to be run on multiple browsers across multiple platforms. I have a windows machine with me so that won't be a problem but coming to safari- Can I run test cases on Mac IOS server created using VM Ware. Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can run your tests on a remote machine. Please follow instructions from our documentation:

1. Open the console and type a command to run tests. Use `remote` as a browser alias to specify that tests should run on a remote machine`testcafe remote tests/test.js`
2. TestCafe prepares a URL for the remote browser to connect to the server.
3. Go to a remote computer that has network access to the machine with TestCafe. Open the browser in which you want to test and navigate to the URL generated by TestCafe.

Please refer to the following article for the details: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/testing-on-remote-computers-and-mobile-devices.html#run-tests-on-a-remote-computer